# Docker run using AWS ECR Public Gallery

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I'm currently building a Lambda layer using

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

build=("pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/ && "
        "lots &&",
        "more &&",
        "commands &&",
        "exit")
docker run -v "$PWD/":/var/task \
    "amazon/aws-sam-cli-build-image-python3.7" \
    /bin/sh -c "${build[*]}"
```

I'm getting throttled by dockerhub, so I'd like to use the [AWS ECR Public Gallery](https://gallery.ecr.aws/).

I tried:

```sh
docker run -v "$PWD/":/var/task \
    "public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7" \
    /bin/sh -c "${build[*]}"
```

But I get `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7: No such file or directory`

How can I do a `docker run` and have it pull from the [AWS ECR Public Gallery](https://gallery.ecr.aws/)?

Answer (score 0):

check if you are already logged in to `docker hub`  in file `~/.docker/config`

```
{
    "auths": {
            "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
    },
    ...
```

if yes then logout via

```
$docker logout
Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

[AWS ECR Public Gallery](https://gallery.ecr.aws/) anyone can pull images.

Just a side note the image you are trying to pull will not have `sam cli` installed. No official image yet published on `gallery.ecr.aws` with `sam cli` yet.

You have to bake your own image with `sam cli`.